# Joomla 2.5 template assign issue

Tags: templates, joomla, menuitem, joomla2.5

i need to assign a diffrent layout for my home page, but my issue is before come to home page there is a login page with totally different layout.i made that template as "default" (Because that should be load first), after logged in comes to home page.Home page doesn't have componet area only have modules.How do i assign my 2nd template only to the home page ?
anyone has any idea how to do that ? please help me! OR any idea to accomplish my objective ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign the template to the 'home' from the template menu, 'home' should be in the main menu.

All other pages should be assigned to the other template.

administrator/index.php?option=com_templates&view=style&layout=edit&id=XXX